# Error 403- Acces Forbideen (xampp)

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, xampp

I installed xampp and postgreql(9.4 version) and downloaded phpPgAdmin. I am using windows 7 64 bit. When i try to acces localhost/phpmyadmin it works, but when I try to acces localhost/phppgamin it doesn't. I want to mention also that postgresql was installed in the xampp folder, and I also modified the extra_login_security to false (config.inc file from the phpPgAdmin folder) and also uncommented the php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql line from php.ini. I tried also to modify the require local lines to require all granted, but still doesn't work.

This is how my httpd-xamp.conf looks like

> #
>
> ## XAMPP settings
>
> #
>
> SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
>       SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\xampp\mysql\bin"
>       SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
>       SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\xampp\php"
>       SetEnv PHPRC "\xampp\php"
>       SetEnv TMP "\xampp\tmp"
>
> #
>
> ## PHP-Module setup
>
> ## LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll" LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll" LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
>
> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php  
>       SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
>
> #
>
> ## PHP-CGI setup
>
> #
>
> ## SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
>
> ## Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
>
> PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
>
> AddType text/html .php .phps
>
> ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/" 
>       AllowOverride None
>       Options None
>       Require all denied
>       
>             Require all granted
>
> SetHandler cgi-script
>       
>       
>           SetHandler None
>
> php_admin_flag safe_mode off
>         
>       
>       AllowOverride AuthConfig
>
> Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
>       
>           Options +Indexes
>           
>               DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
>               DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
>               DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
>               DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
>               DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
>           
>           Require all granted
>           ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
>
> ```
> Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
> <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig
>     Require all granted
>     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
> </Directory>
>
> Alias /phppgadmin "C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin/"
> <Directory "C:/xampp/phpPdAdmin">
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig
>     Require all granted
>     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
> </Directory>
>
> Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
> <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
>     <IfModule php7_module>
>       <Files "webalizer.php">
>           php_admin_flag safe_mode off
>       </Files>
>     </IfModule>
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig
>     Require all granted
>     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
> </Directory> </IfModule>
> ```

Comment: what error message you encounter when access phppgadmin?

Comment: Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6

Comment: normally you don't have to make alias and directory for phppgadmin, just put the folder phppgadmin in the htdocs. try this first

Comment: I did as you said and now I get the "Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Misc has a deprecated constructor in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpPgAdmin\classes\Misc.php on line 8" error.

Comment: i think your phppgadmin is not compatible with php 7